# Strange behaviour of soft link on Big Sur

Tags: macos

The following is a copy of a simple terminal session on Mac OS Big Sur 11.4:

```
1 ~> date
Fri Jul  2 20:16:45 EDT 2021
2 ~> which gmake
3 ~> ll /usr/local/bin/gmake
ls: /usr/local/bin/gmake: No such file or directory
4 ~> /usr/bin/gnumake --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
5 ~> sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gnumake /usr/local/bin/gmake
Password:
6 ~> ll /usr/local/bin/gmake
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  16 Jul  2 20:17 /usr/local/bin/gmake -> /usr/bin/gnumake
7 ~> /usr/bin/gnumake --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
8 ~> /usr/local/bin/gmake --version
gmake: error: Failed to locate 'gmake'.
xcode-select: Failed to locate 'gmake', requesting installation of command line developer tools.
```

And a little window pops up, giving me the choice to install or cancel.  (In this session I cancelled. When I choose install it will succeed after several minutes, but if I invoke `usr/local/bin/gmake` again, the same thing will happen again.)

How is this even possible?

FWIW, the command line tools are already installed:

```
9 ~> xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

Any explanation of this phenomenon would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean to ask on [Ask Different (Apple SE)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I don't have Big Sur (I'm still on Mojave, since I have some 32-bit applications I use daily) but I am suspecting that this "gnumake" you are trying to run is a wrapper shell script that knows of the real installation directory of the various tools. It's probably using $0 (executable name) to redirect the command's execution.

Comment: Doesn't look like a wrapper shell script.  The file is bainary, and largeish:```16 ~> ll /usr/bin/gnumake 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  137600 Jan  1  2020 /usr/bin/gnumake
```